# How did I lose a point of rep in this situation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

On Feb 14 20:01:40Z, [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/284461/movie-about-a-robot-restoring-the-human-population-with-a-machine-that-can-creat/284463#284463) was asked.  At Feb 14 20:08:11Z someone posted a comment asking when the OP saw it.  During those 6-7 minutes, I happened to be looking and found a possible answer which I posted around 20:10:00Z or so, after checking comments and answers to make sure it wasn't a duplicate.  I can't tell you exactly when or what it said, because someone deleted it, but it was something like "if it was recent, it might possibly be [*I Am Mother (2019)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Mother)?".  I didn't post it as an answer because I was at work and didn't have time to do so.

About 15 minutes later (20:25:17Z), the same person who wrote the first comment posted an answer asking "Is this *I Am Mother* (2019)..."?  I noticed this sometime later and graciously (ok, maybe a little sarcastically) commented that he was welcome.

my comments were getting upvotes throughout the day (for what its worth), but when i looked the next day, *both* comments were removed.  Why in the world would my first answer suggestion be removed?

I let it go.  I realize there are people who value rep points to an extreme degree (and it turned out to be right has got him 21 pts so far), though I think for most people, this isn't the case.  But then today I happened to notice I got a -1 pt rep for that question.  How is this possible for a question I didn't answer officially AND had the first correct answer in a comment?

Comment: Comments aren't for answers. That's why your comment likely got deleted. Also, avoid sarcasm in comments. It's easily misunderstood as snark.

Comment: 25 minutes is entirely feasible to read a question, look for and find an answer, and post a reasonably detailed response without looking for comments posted in the interim. In that sort of time frame I would assume parallel research more likely than running with my answer-as-a-comment.

Answer (score 17):

Since you don't have an answer posted, the obvious conclusion is that you downvoted LogicDictates' answer. Downvoting answers [incurs a small rep cost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15863/why-do-you-lose-reputation-for-downvoting-answers) to prevent frivolous use.

The question also has a downvote, but [downvotes on questions are free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free).

---

As to why your answer-as-a-comment was deleted, it's likely this happened because it was no longer needed given there is now an answer to the question that says the same thing.

If you're sour (or salty) about somebody taking your comment and turning it into an answer, then you should have posted it as an answer in the first place.

Comment: For what it's worth, there was a comment on the answer which said something like: "What do you mean 'you're welcome'? I actually found it by searching for the answer too".

Comment: @Clockwork - I can't remember if I was the one that flagged his earlier comments as *'no longer needed'* or *'unfriendly'* but that's almost certainly why they got zapped